# Word Embedding for Item Names(integer, one-hot encoding)

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, word

I am looking for the way to get the similarity between two item names using integer encoding or one-hot encoding.

For example, "lane connector" vs. "a truck crane".
I have 100,000 item names consisting of 2~3 words as above.
also, items have its size(36mm, 12M, 2400*1200...) and unit(ea, m2, m3, hr...)

I wanna make (item name, size, unit) as a vector. To do this, I need to change texts to numbers using some way. All I found is only word2vec things, but my case has no context corpus. So I don't think it is possible to learn some context from my data.

[image: Example Image of dataset]

Comment: Will be good if you provide few samples with complete feature list, possibly will help me in my better understanding.

Comment: Why word2vec or Glove wouldn't be useful for your item names? Also before that you could think of using TF-IDF to construct your vectors, it is very simple and I think it will be better than integer or one-hot encoding.

Comment: @vipinbansal added the image :)

Comment: @TwinPenguins I don't think that I can use those method because of the data

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if it's possible with this data set. Word2Vec is used to generate word embedding, which works on the principle of "words association" in a sentence.

So I dont think you can apply Word2Vec on this dataset which looks like doesn't have any association, except on some places where you can match(perform clustering) some parameters like:

1. Units
2. Size/dimension of the item-name

Interested to know some solution for such types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I understand is you just have a list of words and want to get word vectors for those. You are correct that you cannot train a word2vec model as it requires a corpus. But what you can do is use a pre-trained model (word2vec or glove). I suggest you use word2vec as gensim has a pretty simple implementation. You can download Google’s pre-trained model [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit). And then you can use the following code to get `word_embed` for a given `word_list`.

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
vocab = model.vocab.keys()
word_embed = {}
for word in word_list:
    if word in vocab:
        word_embed.append(model[word])
```

Also, you'll have to apply some pre-processing to your word list so that you can get maximum matches from the pre-trained embeddings (like removing the etc.) And if a word is still not found in the pre-trained embeddings you can either initialize it randomly or take an average of the embeddings.

Comment: Thank you for your solution :) However, my dataset is made of Korean. i just translated it to post here. What I wanna do right now is making a kind of corpus that has mapping structure. It is consist of like {Base item : mapped item1, item2 ...}. I am just thinking of this to solve this problem.